# Flutter: How to get data from array data field from Cloud Firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having a problem with retrieving my data in firestore. I made data in my fields which that data is an array. Now I'm having a problem retrieving it. I use StreamBuilder in my retrieving data. How can I retrieve it? My data is in "ACTIVITIES - RANDOM ID - Issue { array of data that I want to get }". Please help.

My code:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: db.collection('ACTIVITIES').snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Column(
                        children: snapshot.data.documents
                            .map((doc) => buildItem(doc))
                            .toList());
                  } else {
                    return SizedBox();
                  }
                })
```

My Database Structure:

[Link to my DB pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKQVk.png)

Comment: What exactly does your code do that's different than what you expect?  What is `buildItem`?

Comment: Now sir @doug its just outputing a null value, maybe because my code isn't reaching the array field :(